# Is there a way to shortcut typing "xmlns" in Android like <!DOCTYPE html> in HTML 5?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-xml

I hate having to remember and type the same `android:xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` line whenever I'm defining a new XML layout in Android. Is there a way to shortcut that like how `<!DOCTYPE html>` in HTML 5 is magical?

Comment: That's the most unnecessary downvote ever. What's so wrong about trying to lessen your keypresses which many programming languages do for developers?

Comment: Which IDE do you use?  Surely it creates new layouts from a template?

Comment: I'm not talking about IDE shortcuts, I'm talking about syntax. `<!DOCTYPE html>` doesn't have anything to do with any IDE, does it?

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. I thought you were looking for ways to avoid having to manually type in the namespace declaration.  If you are not doing that inside an IDE, then where are you doing it?  BTW, I have NEVER typed xmlns in Android.

Comment: Because you probably always use the IDE wizard that sets the parent element of any new XML layout you create, and never had to replace that parent element with something else and accidentally delete parts of it in the process. I was simply wanted to know if there's a way to syntactically get around it because I don't rely on an IDE like a crutch in my current project.

Comment: Actually, never used a wizard, don't even know if there is one.  But, when I create an XML file, depending on where I do it (i.e. res/raw res/layout) the file is created from a template which I modify to include whatever I want.  For custom text insertion, I use live templates (IntelliJ IDEA).  All I have to do is type {def xmlns} and press tab.  I don't rely on the IDE as a crutch either but templating is why I never have to type a namespace declaration.  Still not a syntatic solution but fits the bill?  BTW, it wasn't me who down voted, not that it's important.

Comment: Well I don't know how IntelliJ is for Android development but I use the common one which is Eclipse. Before it creates an XML file you get to choose from a dialog whether the parent will be `RelativeLayout`, `LinearLayout`, etcetera. Also, I never assumed it was you who downvoted. It's just one point, I can easily get it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just copy/paste this from another layout?

(and the answer about shortcut is "no")